# How to make diamond operator Type arguments dynamic in java?

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

I have a following interface

```
public interface Splitter<T, V> {
    V[] split(T arg);
}
```

Following is the factory method implementation which I am using to get Splitter Implementation.

Factory Method Implementation

```
public static <T, V> Splitter<T, V> getSplitter(Class<T> key1, Class<V> key2) {

    if (key1 == Company.class && key2 == Department.class)
        return (Splitter<T, V>) new CompanySplitterImpl();

    // more cases
}
```

Following is my call at client side which compiles fine

```
Splitter<Company, Department> split = getSplitter(Company.class, Department.class);
```

I want to avoid tight coupling of client side code with the implementation. Is there a way to avoid hardcoded Type params i.e. avoiding use Company and Department (`Splitter<Company, Department>`) at callee side and use some variable instead? Is there a way out through which they can be loaded from some external property file?

FYI : I am not sure about its feasibility in Java?

Comment: Which hardcoded type params are you talking about? And what variable would you want to use?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please provide the code that you would like to have.

Comment: First of all it is impossible. If you ask why then first try to answer this question: How you will use it?

Comment: Your client is using a `Company.class` and a `Department.class` so it's already coupled with them. Can you show a use case where the client is supposed to be agnostic about them?

Comment: That I wouldn't say is tight coupling at all. You're using the interface there, and you've to anyhow give the type argument to declare it's reference. You could have used `CompanySplitterImpl` as reference type, but that IMO would be tight coupling.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think Company.class and Department.class can be dynamically loaded  from some property file and passed into factory method
.

Comment: Good, but then, how do you expect to be able to declare the parameter to `split()` and the array that it returns?

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case, but if the client should not know about the Concrete classes Company and Department, then perhaps Company and Department should be implementing some interfaces that the client will known about.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is have you factory not know anything about concrete implementations and instead have themselves register with it (or contain a predefined list) and ask each implementation if it can handle the types or not.  For example, given a predefined list like your example above:

```
public class SplitterFactory {
    private Set<Splitter> splitters = new HashSet<>() {{
        add(new CompanySplitterImpl());
    }};

    public static <T, V> Splitter<T, V> getSplitter(Class<T> key1, Class<V> key2) 
    {
        for (Splitter splitter : splitters) {
            if (splitter.canAccept(key1, key2)) {
                return splitter;
        }       
        // no matched splitter
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a very naive solution and you could implement the lookup more efficiently.  If you don't know your types at compile time, you could also have a registration mechanism with the factory to include new ones at runtime.  Because the Splitter itself is now responsible for reporting what types it can handle it's fully extensible.

Comment: Your `splitters` set is defined using a raw `Splitter`. Not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple map class that you can list them up to:

```
public final class SplitterMap {

    private final List<SplitterType<?, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private class SplitterType<T, V> {

        private final Class<T> key1;
        private final Class<V> key2;
        private final Class<? extends Splitter<T, V>> clazz;

        private SplitterType(Class<?> key1, Class<?> key2, Class<? extends Splitter<T, V> clazz) {
            this.key1 = key1;
            this.key2 = key2;
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        private boolean matches(Class<?> key1, Class<?> key2) {
            return this.key1 == key1 && this.key2 == key2;
        }
    }

    public <T, V> void put(Class<T> key1, Class<V> key2, Class<? extends Splitter<T, V> clazz) {
        list.add(new SplitterType<T, V>(key1, key2, clazz));
    }

    public <T, V> Splitter<T, V> get(Class<T> key1, Class<V> key2) {
        for (SplitterType<?, ?> type : list) {
            if (type.matches(key1, key2)) {
                try {
                    return ((SplitterType<T, V>) type).clazz.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return null; // not found
    }
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
SplitterMap map = new SplitterMap();
map.put(Company.class, Department.class, CompanySplitterImpl.class);
Splitter<Company, Department> splitter = map.get(Company.class, Department.class);
```

Comment: I tried to test this as a new project to see if it helped me with an similar issue and it seems like it is referencing other dependencies.... Am I missing something or can you specify what the dependencies are used?

Comment: @DVS It's been a while since I posted this answer but there should be no other dependencies besides the types from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way but one way would be:

```
String companyClass = "Company";
String departmentClass = "Department";
Splitter split = getSplitter(Class.forName(companyClass), Class.forName(departmentClass));//raw splitter
System.out.println(split.split(new Company()));//you could use reflection here to create instance from companyClass String.
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I assume you want something like

```
Splitter<Company, Department> s = Splitters.getSplitter()
```

Which is not posible without reflection, because of

1. type erasure
2. return type overloading not available in java yet

Secondly you're abusing FactoryMethod pattern. Which should look more like this:

```
interface Splitter<T, V> {
    V[] split(T arg);
}

interface SplitterFactory {
    <T, V> Splitter<T, V> getSplitter();
}

class CompanySplitterFactory implements SplitterFactory {
    @Override
    public Splitter<Company, Department> getSplitter() {
        return new CompanySplitterImpl();
    }
}
```